# Deserialize Json Response to Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the bellow json response and I am trying to deserialize it to c# object but I am always getting error. 
Json response:

```
"\"{\\\"method\\\":\\\"https://hereisalink.com\\\",\\\"http_method\\\":\\\"POST\\\",\\\"http_code\\\":900,\\\"error_code\\\":\\\"OK\\\",\\\"error_msg\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"params\\\":[],\\\"data\\\":{\\\"summaryUrl\\\":\\\"https://sureyurl.com/?firstparam=123&secondparam=myemail%40gmail%2Ecom\\\",\\\"my_id\\\":1234,\\\"myemail\\\":\\\"theemail@gmail.com\\\",\\\"result\\\":\\\"yes\\\"}}\""
```

My C# object:

```
public class SummaryOBJ
    {

        public string method { get; set; }
        public string http_method { get; set; }
        public string POST { get; set; }
        public string http_code { get; set; }
        public string error_code { get; set; }
        public string error_msg { get; set; }
        public string[] @params { get; set; }
        public Thesummary data { get; set; }

    }
    public class Thesummary
    {
        public string summaryUrl { get; set; }
        public int my_id { get; set; }
        public string myemail { get; set; }
        public string result { get; set; }

    }
```

My C# code to deserialize:

```
//var myresp is the above json response i mention
var myresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummaryOBJ>(myresp);
```

The error i  get:

> Error converting value
>   "{"method":"https://hereisalink.com","http_method":"POST","http_code":900,"error_code":"OK","error_msg":"","params":[],"data":{"summaryUrl":"https://sureyurl.com/?firstparam=123&secondparam=myemail%40gmail%2Ecom","my_id":1234,"myemail":"theemail@gmail.com","result":"yes"}}"
>   to type 'SummaryOBJ'. Path '', line 1, position 383.

Comment: Not sure this is the issue, but `http_code` is serialized as a number and you read it as a string.

Comment: try change `@params` property type from `string[]` to `List<string>`

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this with your code and JSON but it all works as expected, without error. JSON.NET is smart enough to convert the `http_code` to a string for you, so it's not going to be that. Here's a working [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2v9prW).

Comment: Non-repro. Show the actual code with the actual JSON string. Don't simplify your JSON for a question.

Comment: unfortunately i am not simplify my json. This is the response i get with copy paste from QuickWatch.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin you have normalize my json response in the fiddle. The response i have post above is the response i am getting with copy paste. Do you have any suggestion how can i normalize it?

Comment: If possible, you'll want to look at the response that's being sent *server-side*. It appears to be sending a string rather than an object - it's encoding it as JSON and then encoding that as well. Otherwise, you'll have to double-deserialise it in your own code (yuk).

Comment: @Kirk Larkin this was the issue. "you'll want to look at the response that's being sent server-side. It appears to be sending a string rather than an object - it's encoding it as JSON and then encoding that as well.Otherwise, you'll have to double-deserialise it in your own code " Please post this answer so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response that's being returned from the server here is the JSON representation of a string, which is itself the JSON representation of the object you're expecting. The server is first encoding the object as JSON and then *encoding that serialised JSON string* as JSON once again.

You've already confirmed in the comments that the solution to this is to fix the server to encode the data *only once*, so I've written this answer out here for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

`http_code` should be `int` not `string`

Answer (score -1):

```
[
    {
        "method": "https://hereisalink.com",
        "http_method": "POST",
        "http_code": 900,
        "error_code": "OK",
        "error_msg": "",
        "params": [],
        "data": {
            "summaryUrl": "https://sureyurl.com/?firstparam=123&secondparam=myemail%40gmail%2Ecom",
            "my_id": 1234,
            "myemail": "theemail@gmail.com",
            "result": "yes"
        }
    }
]
```

The returned json object should be like this.it looks like your returned json is not in correct format.

your code is correct for DeserializeObject.